# ggplot scatter plot arrange the X axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello creating plot using ggplot2 plot which i am getting I wanted modify x axis values according to my another column values can anyone suggest me group the values according to that column values

sample data

```
  Names    Values   group
  FLAM_C    20.03965    1
  MER112    20.09371    1
  L1MA10    20.11173    1
   L1PB3    20.20184    1
  LTR78B    20.27392    1
  MLT1H1    20.29194    2
   (TG)n    20.30997    2
  Charlie7  20.58028    2
 MamRep605  20.27392    2
   LTR16A   20.47216    2
  Charlie1b 20.94071    3
   L1PA6    20.29194    3
   MLT1G1   20.68841    4
  LTR67B    20.72445    4
  MER58A    20.94071    4
```

script

```
library(ggplot2)
df=read.table("test1",sep='\t', header=TRUE)
df = data.frame(df)
head(df)
ggplot(df, aes(y=Values, x =Names, col=group)) +
  geom_point()
```

test1 is above data from file

Comment: Thanks for data and code but what is wrong? You are not saying what you mean by *to group*. The `color` argument already separates the groups, do you want `facet_wrap(~group)`? Also, you don't need `df = data.frame(df)` since `read.table` outputs a data.frame, it's redundant.

Comment: Do you want `color = factor(group)`?

Comment: @Rui Barradas Sorry want those points segregation according to third column like 1 values segregate first and 2 segregate second I don't need mixed population kind

Comment: Try your plot but with `aes(Names, Values, color = factor(group))` and add `facet_wrap(~group)` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best way to separate the points by `group` is to facet the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Names, y = Values, color = factor(group))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ group, scales = 'free_x') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

If the groups are to be reordered, coerce to factor with the right levels first.

Then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

df1$group <- factor(df1$group, levels = c(3:4, 1:2))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Names, y = Values, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ group, scales = 'free_x') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
library(tidyverse)
test1<-tribble(~Names,    ~Values,   ~group,
"FLAM_C" ,   20.03965,    1,
"MER112"  ,  20.09371,    1,
"L1MA10"   , 20.11173,    1,
"L1PB3",    20.20184,    1,
"LTR78B",    20.27392,    1,
"MLT1H1",    20.29194,    2,
"(TG)n" ,   20.30997,    2,
"Charlie7",  20.58028,    2,
"MamRep605",  20.27392,    2,
"LTR16A",   20.47216,    2,
"Charlie1b", 20.94071,    3,
"L1PA6",    20.29194,    3,
"MLT1G1",   20.68841,    4,
"LTR67B" ,   20.72445,    4,
"MER58A",    20.94071,    4)


ggplot(test1, 
       aes(y=Values, 
           x =fct_reorder(Names, group),  #if you want to change order of group, use fct_reorder(Names, desc(group))
           col=group)) +
  geom_point()
```

I have no idea why you want to arrange based on group but this code should work for you. the trick is fct_reorder.

Comment: I believe the order is by group, not by Values. Anyway, the question is not at all clear on this, `facet_wrap` de-*segregates*  better.

Comment: @AlanKinene thanks for ansr just wanted ask if I wanted 3, 4,1,2 like this order what I have to do..

Comment: @Luckysardar, in that case you use fct_reorder(Names, desc(group)), see the comment in my answer. Although your order is odd, still your intention is not clear as it it would be visually confusing. But just to go with what you want to make group a factor and pass factor levels of 3,4,1,2 then you can fct_reorder Names based on that.